# Adding additional baseclass to block

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to add an existing Block as Baseclass to another Block. (SysML 1.4)

Once the modeling is through, i want to select blocks in the diagram and add attributes like part-nr and supplier. To me, it appeared to be the easiest way to do this by inheritance.

I'm working with C# and the Interop.EA.dll to have better debug info than with a script.

This code works, but it doesn't add the baseclass.

```
EA.Repository m_Repository = Helpers.EAHelper.ActiveModel;
EA.Collection myCollection = m_Repository.GetCurrentDiagram().SelectedObjects;
foreach(object myObject in myCollection)
{
    EA.DiagramObject myDiagramObject = (EA.DiagramObject)myObject;
    EA.Element myElement = m_Repository.GetElementByID(myDiagramObject.ElementID);
    EA.Element Class2Add = Helpers.EAHelper.BaugruppeClass;
    EA.Element newBaseClass = myElement.BaseClasses.AddNew(Class2Add.ElementID.ToString(), Class2Add.Type.ToString());
    if (!newBaseClass.Update())
         System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("ups");
    myElement.BaseClasses.Refresh();
    int count = myElement.BaseClasses.Count;
    myElement.Update();
}
```

Any thoughts what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have issues parsing your terminology. You seem to talk about Base and derived classes, and moving a codeblock between the two. But then your actuall code is not class definitoons, but some raw code with context that just creates a Instance of the Base Class?

Comment: The goal is to have a selected block to inherit of an existing block that is somewhere in the model. Just like adding a generalization connector in a diagram. just without drawing the connector and placing the base block

Comment: This still does not make sense. The only Blocks In C# I know off are code blocks. And those can not inherit in any meaning off the word I know off. Function containing the code blocks can be inherited. Fields and Properties can be inherited. But codeblocks?

Comment: Maybe we are not talking about the same topic... I'm trying to automate a task in the tool Enterprise Architect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `BaseClasses` collection to add a baseclass.

Instead you should use the `Connectors` collection to add a connector of type **Generalization**, and set the target id to the ID of the base class.